# How to apply module wise class mapping for all css files inside a specific folder only

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-loader, webpack-style-loader

How to apply module wise class mapping for all CSS files inside a specific folder only

I have added the code below but it doesn't work

```
  {
    test: /.css$/i,
    use: [
      "style-loader", 
      //"css-loader"
      {
          loader: "css-loader",
          options: {
            importLoaders : 1,
            modules: {
              //localIdentName: "[name][local][hash:base64:5]",
              //localIdentContext: path.resolve(dirname, "src/styles"),
              mode: "local",
              auto: true,
              exportGlobals: true,
              localIdentName: "[name][local]__[hash:base64:5]",
              localIdentContext: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/styles"),
              localIdentHashSalt: "my-custom-hash",
              namedExport: true,
              exportLocalsConvention: "camelCase",
              exportOnlyLocals: false,
            },
            sourceMap: true,
          },
      }
    ],
    
  },
```

My Reactjs folder structure sample is given below

```
src
 styles // Webpack dynamic class should apply for all classes inside this only
  contact.css
  about.css
global.css // Dont apply webpack dynamic class
```

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? We need to see an [mcve] to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Achieved using the following code

```
{
    test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          importLoaders: 1,
          modules: {
            localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
          },
          sourceMap: false
        }
      }
    ],
    include: /\.module\.css$/
  },
  {
    test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      //'css-loader'
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: false
        }
      }
    ],
    exclude: /\.module\.css$/
  },
```

Note: The css file to apply module should have the filename as [yourname].module.css and just include that in a component
For example AboutComponent and COntactComponent add css as follows
about.module.css & contact.module.css